# Need to have two outbound queues on two different servers and queue managers act as primary and secondary

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, failover

Need to have two  outbound queues on two different servers and queue managers act as primary and secondary respectively  if the sending to primary fails want to connect to secondary but as soon as primary become up application must send to primary any spring boot configuration can help? using websphere MQ.

Comment: Suggest you look into Multi-Instance queue managers. And use a comma-separated CONNAME in your connection details.

Comment: I tried that is there any way I can pass different queue manager name for these two diff connection? because I have two different queue managers with different name.

Comment: The solution from @Morag Hughson means that the same queue manager and therefore queues and messages are available when there is a failover. If your primary and secondary are different / unrelated queue mangers, then your overall solution would need to cope with that.

Comment: Connectionname list can be used only in one connectionfactory Can I use it to connect to multiple server with single connectionfactory.

Answer (score 1):

For a Java JMS messaging application in Spring Boot, a [connection name list](https://ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=objects-connectionnamelist) allows for setting multiple `host(port)` endpoints as comma separated pairs.

The connection factory will then try these endpoints in turn to finds an available queue manager. Unsetting `WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER` means the connection factory will connect to the available queue manager on a given `host(port)` endpoint regardless of its name.

You'll need to think about the lifecycle of the connection factory as the connection will remain valid once it has been established. In the scenario where the connection factory is bound to the queue manager on **hostB(1414)** (the second in the list) and then the queue manager on **hostA(1414)** (the first in the list) becomes available again, nothing would change until the next connection attempt.

It's important to note that where the queue manager endpoints in the connection name list are unrelated, then the queues and messages available will not be the same. [Multi-Instance](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=configurations-multi-instance-queue-managers) queue managers allow a queue manager instance to failover between two `host(port)` endpoints. For container deployments, [IBM MQ Native HA](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/david-ware1/2021/03/23/native-ha-cloud-native-high-availability) ensures your messaging applications are routed to an active instance of the queue manager

A CCDT allows for much more sophisticated connection matching options with IBM MQ over the connection name list method outlined above. More information on CCDT is available [here](https://ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=ccdt-json-examples). For JMS applications you'll need to set the connection factory to use CCDT e.g., `cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CCDTURL, "")` to the location of the CCDT JSON file.

Comment: Thanks @richc your answer clarify my doubt. what I understood is I can have a connection factory without passing a QM name but one more thing to clarify host(port) this combination will be unique for each QM in case multiple QM are running on one host So will my connection be able to identify the right QM.

Comment: @SwatiNaroliya Correct - only one QM can be using a specific port on a host.

Comment: Note that there is not, to my knowledge, a good automatic way of achieving your aim to return the connection to your primary QM when it returns to service - using the connection name list approach, any new connections would use the primary, while existing ones would use the secondary until they were disconnected. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=application-automatic-jms-client-reconnection may be of interest in this context.

Comment: @SwatiNaroliya Your original question mentioned the concept of a 'primary' and 'secondary' QM. If both QMs are running on the same host, then the host itself becomes a single point of failure for your messaging resources.

Comment: @MarkBluemel I always want to reconnect to primary as soon as it is up. only in case primary is down it should connect to secondary. How can I handle this situation any reference.

Comment: As a general rule, it is good practice for clients to disconnect and reconnect periodically to help with workload balance.  For example  you have 2 servers. ServerA is down.  all clients connect to ServerB.  ServerA starts, and gets no clients.   Server B's system is overloaded - Server A is idle.  If the clients disconnect a) after an idle period ( perhaps half an hour)  or b) every hour +- 10 minutes (to get a random time) then the enterprise workload balancers can route the connection to the best system ( eg lightest load).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth me putting up an answer rather than more comments, though most of the ground has been covered by Rich's answer, augmented by Rich's, Morag's and my comments.

[Client Reconnection](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=application-automatic-jms-client-reconnection) seems the most natural fit for the first part of the use-case, and I'd suggest using a connection name list rather than going to the complexity of using a CCDT for this job. This will ensure that the application connects to your primary queue manager if it's available and the secondary queue manager if the primary isn't available, and will also move applications to the secondary if the primary fails.

Once a connection has been made, in general it won't move. The two exceptions are that in client reconnection configuration, a connection will be migrated to a different queue manager if communication to the first is broken, and in the context of [uniform clusters](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=cluster-about-uniform-clusters) connections may be requested to migrate to a queue manager to balance load over the cluster. There is no automatic mechanism that I can think of which would force *all* the connections back from your secondary queue manger to the primary - you'd need to either do something with the application, or in a client reconnect setup you could bounce the secondary queue manager.

(You could use [this forum](https://bigblue.aha.io/products/MESNS/ideas_overview) to request such a feature, but I can't promise either that the request would be accepted or that it would be rapidly acted on.)

If you want to discuss this further, I'd suggest that more dialogue is probably needed to help us understand your scenario properly, so that we can make the most helpful recommendations. [The MQ discussion forum](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/communities/community-home/digestviewer?communitykey=183ec850-4947-49c8-9a2e-8e7c7fc46c64) may be a useful place for such dialogue, as it doesn't fit well (IMHO) to the StackOverflow model.